# Can $\sum_{x}^{\infty}$ be always rewitten as $\sum_{x+y}^{\infty}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $x,y$ be arbitrary but fixed and integers.

Can then $\sum_{x}^{\infty}$arbitrary term

be always rewritten as

some constant $c$ + $\sum_{x+y}^{\infty}$some other term?

It seems so for me, but I'm not sure if I can proof it for literally every term that gets added.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795150

Answer (score 0):

if you mean something like $\sum_{k=a}^\infty =\sum_{k=a}^{a+b-1}+\sum_{k=a+b}^\infty$ and then $c=\sum_{k=a}^{a+b-1}$ this is always ok and self explaining.It needs no extra proof.